# How to implement a custom consensus mechanism in Ganache

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, ganache, consensus

As a beginner in the Ethereum world, I have developed a blockchain network in Ethereum using Truffle, Ganache and Web3.js. I can deploy smart contract to Ganache network and transactions are included in a block, however I want to create a use-case specific consensus mechanism which depends on the variables in the smart contract.

Ganache seems to use create a block when a transaction occurs as the default mechanism. My question is how can I change the consensus mechanism in Ganache, is there a way for customization? If not, should I use geth in my system and change the consensus.go file there? I understand that if I use Geth, Ganache network will be useless. Can I still use the Web3.js code and the smart contracts written in Solidity if I use geth as a client?

I will appreciate any of your help.

Comment: Ganache is an open source testing client. You could modify its source to suit your needs. It won't be easy, but it is doable. Ganache and geth are both based on the EVM, so they are compatible at the smart contract level. Similar to ganache, geth is open source and modifying it is doable by an advanced developer but adding new features isn't easy if you aren't accustomed to the inners working.